# How to output eval in function or class Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, class, variables

I want dynamic variables just by input number of variables, I wrote a function which `eval` the correct desire but outside function, variables aren't accessible unfortunate, How ever I tried `varargout`  but `eval` can't be achieved by assignment operator `=`.

**My function:**

```
function varargout = dynamicVariables(n)
for ii=1:n

eval( strcat(['var' num2str(ii) '1'],'=','2'));
end
return;
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use consecutive variable names, use a vector instead.

```
function v = dynamicVariables(n)
v=nan(n,1)
for ii=1:n
   v(ii)=2
end
end
```

Comment: OK, it seems cool, what about if I have the following sitution of `eval`.
`eval( strcat(['Obj' num2str(ii) 'Object'],'=','var1'));`

Comment: The eval-function should be avoided whenever possible: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html